# Change Resharper 9 simple property auto formatting

Tags: resharper, visual-studio-2015

I've recently started using VS2015 and Resharper 9.
I encounter a weird formatting with the default configuration (it was ot present in VS2013/Resharper8) :

If I try to auto format this piece of code:

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
```

It goes to:

```
    public int Id
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public string Login
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public string Password
    {
        get; set;
    }
```

But I want it to stay as it where (like in the previous version). I've tried to tick the "Place property/indexer/event declaration on single line" but it changed nothing.

Answer (score 1):

So I agree with Karel Kral, in that it seems to be a Visual Studio setting, however the setting I believe is "Leave block on single line" which needs to be checked to stop this annoying behavior.

Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Formatting > Wrapping > "Leave block on single line"

Answer (score 0):

Try ticking "ReSharper | Options | Code Editing | C# | Formatting Style | Line Breaks and Wrapping | Place abstract/auto property/indexer/event declaration on single line" instead of "Place property/indexer/event declaration on single line"

Comment: How did you launch formatting - via ReSharper | Tools | Cleanup Code? By the way, what EAP build do you use (ReSharper | Help | About ReSharper Platform)?

Comment: Resharper 9 EAP 7 and I format with Ctrl + K, Ctrl + D

Comment: Ctrl + K, Ctrl + D is Visual Studio action, not ReSharper one, so it does not follow ReSharper options. To adjust such behavior in VS, tick Tools | Options | Text Editor | C# | Formatting | Wrapping | Leave block on single line.

Comment: I checked it but no result ..., I'm starting to wndering if it's not a VS15 bug. I will try to report it on the microsoft forums

Comment: Please try running ReSharper | Tools | Cleanup Code | select "Default: Reformat code". Will it produce desired formatting?

Comment: indeed it does, so it's the formatting of VS15 itself which act weirdly.

Comment: It is not Resharper who is doing this reformat. It is VS 2015 itself. Leave block on single line does not work. I have found no option which works.

Answer (score 0):

It is VS 2015 itself, which does this reformat. After long investigating, I have found option that affects this beavior. "Leave statements and member declarations on the same line" must be checked

[image: Leave statements and member declarations on the same line]

Comment: Actually it's "Leave block on single line"